# Batch files get rid of iterator number in the output

Tags: mysql, for-loop, batch-file

I wrote a batch file that will loop through the contents of a directory and execute a mysql command for each file.

Here is the code:

```
SET FilePath=D:\COUNTR~1\blah\*.sql

FOR %%a IN (%FilePath%) DO mysql -u root -plinuxsux blah < "%%a"
```

In the command line in Windows, it comes back as this:

```
mysql -u root -plinuxsux blah 0<"absolute\path\to\my\sql\file.sql"
```

How the hell do I get rid of that stupid iteration "0" before the "<" symbol?  I googled it and can't find anything.  Thanks.

Btw, the mysql command still executes successfully and shows up in the database.

Answer (score 2):

The `0` that is added is the marker for `stdin` which is what the file is getting fed into. I'd probably suggest adding `@ECHO OFF` to the beginning of your batch script to get rid of the automatic echoing of the command line.

If you still want to see what file is being processed, you could expand your `FOR` loop with something like this.

```
FOR %%a IN (%FilePath%) DO (
    ECHO Processing %%a...
    mysql -u root -plinuxsux blah < "%%a"
)
```

Refer to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for more information on redirection and the common handles (i.e. `stdin`, `stdout`).

Comment: So does the 0 affect anything?  Cause if not I'll just ECHO OFF.

Comment: The `0` does not affect anything. It's just the full form of `<input_file.txt`. You could write `0<intput_file.txt` and it would do the same thing. The short form is just a little more convenient in case you forget that `0 = stdin`